# Kill setTimeout on Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

I have popover which is used for submitting feedback/question. User can submit the feedback/questions through it. I have two states of popover:

1. Initial state, Shows text-box and submit button
2. Success State, Shows big fa-check-circle for success.

Success popover should disappear in 5 seconds so i have setTimeout set to 5000 which destroy the success and and re-initialize popover to initial state.

There is a possibility that user can click the triggering control back to hide the success state. If user do so, it should hide/destroy the success state and re-initialize the popover. I handled the click event of triggering control and check if popover is visible using below code.

```
$('.questionIcon').data('bs.popover').tip().hasClass('in')
```

If popover visible hide/destroy and re-initialize it to initial state. The problem here is setTimeout might be still on on the Success popover. how can make my popover force to ignore the timeout execute my code ? Came to know that can use clearTimeout but how on popover ?

Comment: One *hackish* type of way would be to have a conditional inside the timeout context block, which checks if it should execute via some kind of global state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the success pops over, you have to set the time out and store the timeout object in a variable as,

```
const timerObj = setTimeout(function(){closePopPver()},5000);
```

And when the user click the triggering control back to hide the success state,, in that onclick you can write,

```
onclick={function(){clearTimeout(timerObj)}}
```

Edit: Another method would be to set a flag when the user click say, `reintialised = true`. Then inside the timeout function, you can check this flag,

```
setTimeout(function(){
  if(!reintialised) closePopPver()
},5000);
```

Comment: this makes sense to me, tried but not working! i should declare const timerObj globally and assign the timeout code and then use clearTimeout on click event. what could be missing here ?!

Comment: Why? What is the problem? Still pop upcloses after timeout? Are you sure its the timeout that closes the pop over after reintialising it?

Comment: how can i check in browser what's happening when i click the button ?

Comment: In the source tab of your developer console, you can put breakpoints. And click on your UI to see whether its hitting those lines of codes.

Comment: I have added an alternte approach, you may try that too.

Comment: i found out that in the initial stage when i click the triggering element back and forth, it gives me value of $('.questionIcon').data('bs.popover').tip().hasClass('in') true/false but in success state it's always stays true!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172097/discussion-between-dharappatel-and-rohith-murali).

Answer (score 0):

Bind `setTimeout()` to a variable and pass it to [`clearTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) in your popover handler.

```
var myTimeout = window.setTimeout(function(){ doSomething(); },5000);
window.clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```